# Bootstrap 3 with fullscreen background slider always suddenly jumps to the top of the page on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, browser, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullscreen, viewport

my problem is that when I scroll down in an mobile browser where the menu bar vanishes (e.g. chrome) my background tries to adjust for the larger screen height.

When scrolling up again the menu bar of chrome appears again and reduces the screen height calling my background to shrink again and then suddenly jumps to the beginning of the page.

This looks like hickups and destroys the usability of the page.

the domain is www.kaufbar-muelheim.de

Any clues how to resolve this problem?

THX

Philipp

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the div id="maximage", and do all the work on the body.

Just give the body the following css:

```
body { 
    background-size: auto 100%; 
}
```

And cycle the background by changing the background-image on the body tag.
This will avoid all the calculations for the image size, and gives you the same result.
The problem, is that you would probably have to preload all the background images somehow. As the images are not in the DOM anymore.